# Void redefinition in C

Tags: c

i have the following voids in my code:

```
void multMat1(int n, float* A, float* B, float* C) {
    int i, j, k; // 1
    float sum = 0.0; // 1
    PrintMat(n, A);
    PrintMat(n, B);
    /* This is ijk loop order. */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) // n + 1
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) { // 
            for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
                C[i + j * n] += A[i + k * n] * B[k + j * n]; // C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j]; (a)Version ij k
        }
    PrintMat(n, C);
}

void PrintMat(int n, float* M) {
    int i, j;

    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        //printf("; \n");
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            printf("%.3f ", M[i + j * n]);
        printf("; \n");
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

What i want it's to print a matrix with the method `PrintMat` and i'm calling it in my `mulMat1` void, but the code raises the error: `C2371 'PrintMat' new definition; basic distinct types`
¿How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Learn about forward declarations.

Comment: Details matter so please provide a complete [mre]. It is likely that you do not have a forward declaration of `PrintMat`. Which means when `multMat1` calls `PrintMat` the compiler ends up using a default definition which then conflicts with the real definition later on. Add a forward declaration of move `PrintMat` to be before where it is first called.

Comment: Also, "void" is not the name of the objects that cause the trouble. They are called "functions." "void" means that these functions do not return a value.

Comment: The TL;DR: Move `PrintMat` above `multMat1` in the file in lieu of a forward declaration (as others have suggested)